# How to include/exclude a member in CUBESET when doing a topcount

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula is currently:

```
=CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","TopCount([Retailer].[storenumber].[All].children,281,([Measures].[Sum of SALES_QTY],[Retailer].[BRAND_NAME].[All].[BrandXYZ]))","Formula")
```

In one variation, I would like to include more than just one brand. I.e. `topcount` members in `BrandXYZ` AND `BrandABC`.

In another variation, I would like to exclude a brand. I.e. `topcount` all members EXCEPT `BrandXYZ`.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Appreciate if you can share some sample data/screenshot of the case for others to assist. (: